# Is there any specific term for "English-originated?

Tags: terminology, borrowing

I'm working on an academic writing in English, but as a non-native speaker, I feel lacking of vocabulary.

When a word has its origin in the Chinese language, we use the term 'Sino-' such as Sino-Korean or Sino-Japanese. And I wonder if there is such a thing for English-originated? I'd like to refer to some loanwords from English but in accordance with the 'Sino-'.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may be a question for [ell.se]

Comment: [Anglo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anglo-#English)

Comment: If it's a question about linguistic terminology, it is *entirely* within scope. Ugh, StackExchange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicism

> An Anglicism is a word or construction borrowed from English into another language.

Or, more prosaically (and more common), *English loan*.

OP asks for a counterpart to Sino-, which as @boiko points out, is Anglo-. But as a prefix in *Sino-Korean* and *Sino-Japanese*, Sino- has a connotation of hybridisation, or at least deeply enmeshed bilingualism (*Sino-Korean* = Chinese as spoken in Korea, Sinicised Korean). The counterpart to that with *Anglo-* is, if anything, Anglo-Norman: Norman French as spoken in England (and itself a source of loans into English).

*Anglo-Korean* would not work: it implies routine codeswitching and bilingualism. The connotation is much too strong for the present-day loans from English into Korean, which does not involve the same level of influence as *Sino-Korean*.